# How to convert workspace coordinates to screen coordinates?

Tags: delphi, coordinates, delphi-2009

I want to convert the workspace coordinates returned by `GetWindowPlacement` in `rcNormalPosition.Left` and `rcNormalPosition.Top` to screen coordinates that I can assign later to `MainForm.Left` and `MainForm.Top`. How can I do that ?

Comment: I don't understand your question because it is the same. I've made a small test here: http://pastebin.com/uQyCZrB1 and it is allways the same

Comment: @JensBorrisholt It is not the same. Consider when the taskbar is top or left aligned, for instance.

Comment: When saving and restoring form position I strongly recoemnd you also save yourself some additional information regarding workspace setup at the time of application closure. Why? It is posible that workspace settings have changed since the last run of your application (last time the aplication migh have been shown on second monitor that is no longer conected). Failing to detect this you might go and position your application outside of curent visible area. I have seen many application that failed to do this and it can be Quite pain in the ass to get such application back into visible area.

Comment: @Silver saving the workspace is not the way forward. Simply force the window to be visible given the current workspace. That will protect you against all hidden form failure modes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you simply force the window to be visible, then you are stripping the user of a chance to prearange the application window/s placment which best suits that user needs. And that is exactly what OP seems to be trying to offer his application users. Now I have seen applications which not only store workspace information just for making sure that upon next start the application window Will be placed in visible area but to also provide the user to be able to design seperate application layouts for different workspace setups. This can be extreemly usefull for laptop owners.

Comment: @Silver You don't need to store workspace as well as coords rel to workspace to achieve any of that. You are over thinking this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How will you then determine which workplace setup is currentl available?

Comment: @SilverWarior Why would you need to do that? The user knows which layout is needed, because the user can see which set of monitors are connected. I suppose that if you are building something which dynamically adapts to the monitors that are available, then it gets more complex. But I don't think the question was about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest and cleanest way is to use the API function that partners with `GetWindowPlacement`, namely [`SetWindowPlacement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633544.aspx). That way you don't need to convert between workspace and screen coordinates because you let the system do the work for you.

```
var
  WindowPlacement: TWindowPlacement;
....
WindowPlacement.length := SizeOf(WindowPlacement);
Win32Check(GetWindowPlacement(Handle, WindowPlacement));
....
Win32Check(SetWindowPlacement(Handle, WindowPlacement));
```

In the above code, `Handle` is assumed to be the window handle of the form.

If you have persisted the left and top then you'd restore them like this:

```
var
  WindowPlacement: TWindowPlacement;
....
WindowPlacement.length := SizeOf(WindowPlacement);
Win32Check(GetWindowPlacement(Handle, WindowPlacement));
WindowPlacement.rcNormalPosition.Left := NewLeft;
WindowPlacement.rcNormalPosition.Top := NewTop;
Win32Check(SetWindowPlacement(Handle, WindowPlacement));
```

Comment: When I use `SetWindowPlacement` I must set all the members of the `WindowPlacement` structure ? Because I don't understand all of them...

Comment: You called `GetWindowPlacement` which initialized the struct. There's nothing for you to set.

Comment: I want to get the placement, save it in registry and next time the program starts restore the placement.

Comment: So go ahead and do just that. Either persist all members of the struct, or just the pos. If you do the latter than call `GetWindowPlacement` to fill out the ones you don't persist.

Comment: FTR, this solution has no side effect because of not updating FLeft, FTop as one might suspect, because they are updated in `WM_WINDOSPOSCHANGED`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `monitor` property of your form to determine if the workspace of the monitor that the form is on has got any offset with the monitor's placement. E.g.

```
ScreenLeft := wplc.rcNormalPosition.Left + 
                Monitor.WorkareaRect.Left - Monitor.Left;
ScreenTop := wplc.rcNormalPosition.Top + 
                Monitor.WorkareaRect.Top - Monitor.Top;
```