# Wrong window position values when program is being closed while minimized

Tags: delphi, desktop-application, delphi-xe8, window-position

On my Windows 7 desktop, I have the Windows Taskbar attached at the LEFT side of the screen (instead of default on the bottom) and a custom desktop toolbar ("True Launch Bar") attached at the TOP of the screen.

In a Delphi XE8 VCL project, I save the main window position values (`formMain.Top` and `formMain.Left`) in the `FormClose` event, and then at program start I restore the main window position with these values in the `FormCreate` event.

This normally works well. **However**, when the program is closed while MINIMIZED (`formMain.WindowState` = `wsMinimized`) then the form position values are wrong (i.e. REDUCED by the width/height of the toolbars) and so the window is restored at a wrong position at program start.

So how can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**: I tried the [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897863/delphi-form-restored-state-position-and-size) mentioned by David:

```
var
  WindowPlacement: TWindowPlacement;
  R: TRect;
....
  WindowPlacement.Length := SizeOf(WindowPlacement);
  Win32Check(GetWindowPlacement(formMain.Handle, @WindowPlacement));
  R := WindowPlacement.rcNormalPosition;
  CodeSite.Send('formMainLeft by WinAPI', R.Left);        // normal: 323 minimized: 323
  CodeSite.Send('VCL formMain.Left',      formMain.Left); // normal: 423 minimized: 323
```

However, this produces the same problem, as it does not take into account the space occupied by the toolbars, as it gets only the WORK AREA values.

Moreover, this is not a duplicate question as mentioned by David, but a SIMILAR question. This problem derives from wrong screen values when in Minimized state, while the other question is about overall restoring state and size.

Please also note: I do NOT want to restore the window state (e.g. Minimized) AND position, but ONLY the window position, so I cannot use `SetWindowPlacement` as mentioned by David in the other question.

**EDIT2**: I have now solved the problem with this code:

```
  if formMain.WindowState = wsMinimized then
  begin
    MinimizedOffsetTop  := Screen.WorkAreaTop;
    MinimizedOffsetLeft := Screen.WorkAreaLeft;
  end
  else if formMain.WindowState = wsNormal then
  begin
    MinimizedOffsetTop  := 0;
    MinimizedOffsetLeft := 0;
  end;
  SettingsIni.WriteInteger('Persistence', 'Top',  formMain.Top  + MinimizedOffsetTop);
  SettingsIni.WriteInteger('Persistence', 'Left', formMain.Left + MinimizedOffsetLeft);
```

(In the case the window is Maximized, I do not save and restore the window position but do only save and restore the Maximized window state).

Comment: You can use JediVCL library, where there are `TJvFormPlacement` and `TJvFormStorage` components that do auto-save and auto-restore

Comment: Whilst JEDI no doubt has useful classes for this, including JEDI generally forces you to include huge numbers of dependencies. Over the top to reach two Win32 APIs.

Comment: I do not want to use JEDI for this purpose, as I want to keep full control over the saving and restoring myself.

Comment: @kobik `GetWindowRect` gets wrong values when the window is minimized. For example: `R.Left` then becomes -32000!

Comment: Do not use screen.workareatop/left,  your form may not be on a monitor that has the same offset of the work area with the primary monitor. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747238/how-to-convert-workspace-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates

Comment: @DavidHeffernan depends upon how much you would use and upon Smart Linker :-D

Comment: @Arioch It's not so much the exe size. More the source management. And when it's so simple to implement this feature it hardly seems worth bringing in an entire library.

Comment: @Arioch'The I now use TJvFormStorage component with TJvAppIniFileStorage component - it works very well. However, there is only one very small issue: When I first maximize the window, then minimize it, then close the program, then reopen the program, the window is not restored to its maximized size as one maybe might expect, but to the size before it was maximized.

Comment: @user1580348 so you say minimized state is not restored on program launch. I think it is intended. Unless the program is designed to start minimized and hidden (for example using tray icons for user interface), the user would most probably be very confused if the program would be launched minimized and he would not see the main form of it after launch. I guess that is the reason that minimized state is ignored when restoring window state.

Comment: @user You are making such a meal of this. It astounds me that you cannot do this with all the help you've had. And now you want to use JEDI. What has that got to do with the question you asked.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Your behavior IMO is too negative. Please try to be more constructive!

Comment: Read your comments to my answer and tell me they are constructive. You have rejected the function that is designed to solve your problem. You say you don't want to use GWP although you are using it even though you don't know you are using it. You can use SWP or the code that Sertac gave you. Why you reject solutions that work is bizarre. On the face of it, it would seem that you don't want to be helped.

Answer (score 1):

When a window is minimized, it remembers the last normalized bounds and will restore itself there when you restore the window. These bounds are made available to you through `GetWindowPlacement`. This API returns work area relative coordinates.  It does so because that allows for a window to be minimized and restored to the same work area relative location, even if the work area has changed in the intervening time.

Clearly the VCL calls `GetWindowPlacement` when you ask for `Left` and `Top` of a minimized window. How else would it get the coordinates it returns? And of course, it returns work area relative coordinates which is what is confusing you. One might consider it a bug that these properties are sometimes screen relative and other times work area relative.

Your solution is obvious though. Obtain work area relative coordinates by calling `GetWindowPlacement`. When you need to re-apply these coordinates, do so by calling `SetWindowPlacement`.

You say that you cannot use `SetWindowPlacement` because that forces the window to be minimized. But that's not the case. Set the `showCmd` member to `SW_SHOWNORMAL` or `SW_RESTORE`.

We've been using these APIs to store and restore window positions for many many years. They are known to work well.

Comment: David, if this is so easy to implement, why don't you please provide a sample code which demonstrates these 3 steps: 1. GetWindowPlacement, 2. SAVE WindowPlacement to an INI file, 3. Restore WindowPlacement FLEXIBLY, e.g. restore a window at the same place on a second monitor when it was minimized at step one and should be normal when restored. Thank you!

Comment: That comment removes my incentive to do more. Anyway, you've already got a solution that you are happy with. I wrote this answer for other readers.

Comment: No, I am not happy with it, as when the window is minimized on the second monitor (which does not have a left toolbar), it is not restored correctly. So I am looking for another solution. But you did not PROVE your assertion with sample code. PLEASE do that.

Comment: If you aren't happy with it please remove it. Anyway, you've already shown perfectly good GWP code, taken from one of my answer I suspect. Call SWP in the same way, modifying `showCmd` as I say in the answer. You can do this. You've already called SWP. Just make that change to `showCmd`.

Comment: No, not taken from your answer. Why are you so afraid of showing some code? You could earn good points from it.

Comment: I don't care about rep. If you can't work out how to call SetWindowPlacement then spoon feeding won't help. According to your question you already did call SWP though. So all you need to do is set `showCmd`. Do you know how to set a member of a record. Perhaps that's what you don't know how to do. It's `WindowPlacement.showCmd := SW_RESTORE;`

Comment: What is so bad about spoon feeding? It is an act of love. Why people must always be warriors?

Comment: I know you can do this.

Comment: I'm surprised when someone doesn't read comments to his/her question, @user you have the solution for multi monitor setups in a link in a comment to the question. The comment briefly explains the reason too. SetWindowPlacement, solution proposed here, may sometimes require some special attention as it will lead to primitive showing of the form. E.g. you may find some OnEnter handling execute before the form is 'show'n. Chances are that, though, you won't have to modify any additional code.

Comment: @Sertac I'm not sure I understand your objections to GWP/SWP.

Comment: @David the form's window will be shown before the VCL calls ShowWindow. That will change some execution order in VCL's scheme, like alignment code running before the form becomes 'visible', or like my prior example.That may or may not require code alteration. I'm not objecting, just warning...

Comment: @Sertac I've never experienced any such problems, but I'm sure you are right